# array elements not shown as equal

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, one which is from an output source and the other is my own input that I am using to compare values using 5 of the 7 elements.
Eventually I want to create a search routine.

**PROGRAM SEGMENT**

```
// first array - only need elements 2 to 7
$array = array(1974, 13/12/2018, 1, 17, 22, 36, 39, 42);

// use elements 2 to 7 to create new array
$array = array_slice($array, 2, 7, true);

// second array - my input to check if same
$mydraws_array = array(1, 17, 22, 36, 39, 42);

// check if same elements
function same_keys ($a1, $a2) {
    $same = false;
    if (!array_diff_key($a1, $a2)) {
        $same = true;
        foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v) && !same_keys($v, $a2[$k])) {
                $same = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $same;
}

echo "var_dump same_keys"; var_dump(same_keys( $array, $mydraws_array ));

echo "joker draws"; echo"<br />";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>"; echo"<br />";

echo "mydraws elements"; echo"<br />";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($mydraws_array); echo "</pre>"; echo"<br />";

echo "var_dump array_intersect_key"; var_dump(array_intersect_key( $array, $mydraws_array ));

echo "var_dump array_diff_key"; var_dump(array_diff_key( $array, $mydraws_array ));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
var_dump same_keys

boolean false

joker draws

Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 22
    [5] => 36
    [6] => 39
    [7] => 42
)


mydraws elements

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 22
    [3] => 36
    [4] => 39
    [5] => 42
)


var_dump array_intersect_key

array (size=4)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '17' (length=2)
  4 => string '22' (length=2)
  5 => string '36' (length=2)

var_dump array_diff_key

array (size=2)
  6 => string '39' (length=2)
  7 => string '42' (length=2)
```

The input file is coded in utf-8.
Why are they not equal and why are keys 6 and 7 shown using array_diff_key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will keep the keys from the initial array, so as you can see it has keys 2 onwards, whereas the `$mydraws_array` is created from fresh and so will be created with keys 0 on.

If you use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the sliced array, this will reset the keys and they will start from 0.

```
// use elements 2 to 7 to create new array
$array = array_values(array_slice($array, 2, 7, true));
//$array = array_slice($array, 2, 7, true);
```

Comment: var_dump same_keys gives me boolean false even when using $array = array_values ($array); after the reset.

Comment: Just checked it and I get `var_dump same_keys...: bool(true)`

Comment: Ah, okay, I changed the lines as follows and bool = true:                       $array = array_slice($array, 2, 7, true);
echo "array_slice <pre>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>"; echo"<br />";

$array = array_values ($array);
echo "array_values <pre>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>"; echo"<br />";

Answer (score 0):

Using the `array_diff_key` function, it finds what keys are in the first array, that isn't in the second array passed. Read more on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php. The `array_slice` function still retains the initial keys of its array.

This can be solved in two ways:

1. If your more interested in the values than the keys, substitute `array_diff_key` function with `array_diff` function. It would switch consideration to values rather than keys. (**Recommended** - saves on performance)
2. Use the `array_values` function with the `array_slice` function, to re-index the sliced array again.

Comment: Actually I am interested in comparing the values.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about order (I've flipped a pair of numbers in your draws):

```
<?php

$array = array(1974, 13/12/2018, 1, 17, 22, 36, 39, 42);

$slice = array_slice($array, -6);
$draws = array(17, 1, 22, 36, 39, 42);

function same_values(array $one, array $two)
{
    sort($one);
    sort($two);

    return $one === $two;
}

var_dump(same_values($slice, $draws));
var_dump(same_values([], []));
var_dump(same_values([1], [1,1]));
var_dump(same_values([1,2], [2,1]));
var_dump(same_values(['a' => 1, 'b' => 2], ['c' => 2, 'b' => 1]));
var_dump(same_values(['a' => '1', 'b' => '2'], ['c' => 2, 'b' => 1]));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```